# Logical Operations on Big Integers in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, biginteger, logical-operators, varchar

I'm using Apache XAMPP server. I need to perform logical operations on big integers, something like 5 (101) & 2 (010) = 0 (000). Unfortunately my big integers exceeds the maximum of MySQL BIGINT which is 18446744073709551615.

An example of my used numbers is 455214730926009756012878233, so instead of BIGINT i used VARCHAR, i need to perform logical operations on this VARCHAR.
I tried something like

```
SELECT number FROM table WHERE number & 12 = 12
```

it doesn't return the right rows.
And  when i try something like

```
SELECT number FROM table WHERE number &  455214730926009756012878233 = 455214730926009756012878233
```

it gives me no rows, while it should return the row in which the number is '455214730926009756012878233'

So, what is the right way to do logical operations on real big integers like this in MySQL?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the logical operators or big integers. You have an extra `1` after the `where` causing a syntax error.

Comment: Yes, thank you, didn't notice that, it's automatically added by the query suggester.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not about logical operators (those handle Boolean values), but about bitwise operators.

In MySQL v5.7 bitwise operators are [restricted to bigints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html):

> Currently, bit functions and operators require BIGINT (64-bit integer)
>   arguments and return BIGINT values, so they have a maximum range of 64
>   bits. Arguments of other types are converted to BIGINT and truncation
>   might occur.

1) You may consider upgrading to v8.0 because it [supports binary strings as operands](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html) to bitwise operations:

> In MySQL 8.0, bit functions and operators permit binary string type arguments (BINARY, VARBINARY, and the BLOB types) and return a value of like type, which enables them to take arguments and produce return values larger than 64 bits. Nonbinary string arguments are converted to BIGINT and processed as such, as before.

However, v8.0 is still under development at this moment, so this could be a risky move for a production database.

2) You may try to split your large number into multiple 64 bit numbers, perform the operations on each part. For this to work efficiently, I would store the numbers in a hexadecimal format as opposed to standard decimal format because you can get the various parts by reading a fixed number of characters (16) from the string and use it for the conversion.

```
    select * from yourtable
    where left(`fieldname`,16) & left(X'1788b7802c8530419999999',16)=left(X'1788b7802c8530419999999')
      and right(fieldname,char_length(fieldname)-16) & right(X'1788b7802c8530419999999',char_length(X'1788b7802c8530419999999')-16)=right(X'1788b7802c8530419999999',char_length(X'1788b7802c8530419999999')-16)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built in to do binary operations on `VARCHAR`. And as `VARCHAR` is  a text type, I wouldn't consider it appropriate anyway.

Better store the numbers in a numeric type, e.g. `DECIMAL(39,0)`. For bitwise operations split this into two 64 bit parts:

```
select 
  (455214730926009756012878231 DIV 18446744073709551616) as highbits,
  (455214730926009756012878231 %   18446744073709551616) as lowbits,
  (455214730926009756012878231 %   18446744073709551616) % 12
```

18446744073709551616 is 2^64. Don't use `POW(2, 64)`. This function is buggy and results in an incorrect 18446744073709552000 (in MySQL 5.7.2 at least; I suppose MySQL uses approximate math with approximate datatypes here).